# List of camera's angle of view for Android devices

Tags: android, camera

I'm doing some Augmented Reality Android app and I need the camera's angle of view to compute the position of my AR object on the screen. Anybody knows where I could find this data for most used Android devices? I know I can get it from the API since version 8 but I'm using version 7...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't focus only on API 7. 
Devices with API 8 and higher is now more than 75% and it is still growing.

Read this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html

Use reflection to access API 8 in devices with API 8 and higher. In devices with lower API implement it yourself (for example by testing AR on real devices).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll do that. I still need camera's angle of view for the 25% devices with API < 8 though.